# Infinite Loop on angularJS app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following config.js piece of code

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {

    // Configure Idle settings
    IdleProvider.idle(5); // in seconds
    IdleProvider.timeout(120); // in seconds

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard_1");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
        debug: true
    });

    $stateProvider

        .state('dashboards', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboards",
            templateUrl: "viewsangular/common/content.html",
        })
        .state('dashboards.dashboard_1', {
            url: "/dashboard_1",
            templateUrl: "viewsangular/dashboard_1.html",
            resolve: {
                loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        {
                            serie: true,
                            name: 'angular-flot',
                            files: ['Scripts/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.spline.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js', 'Scripts/plugins/flot/angular-flot.js', ]
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angles',
                            files: ['Scripts/plugins/chartJs/angles.js', 'Scripts/plugins/chartJs/Chart.min.js']
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'angular-peity',
                            files: ['Scripts/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js', 'Scripts/plugins/peity/angular-peity.js']
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
  });
}
angular
    .module('inspinia')
    .config(config)
    .run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
```

I know the link to the view is correct.

However I get the following error
http://screencast.com/t/9dNPbBKl10aL

and the page is in infinite loop, from
https://localhost/viewsangular/index.html#

to
https://localhost/viewsangular/index.html#/Dashboards/Dashboard1

The view files are there.
http://screencast.com/t/QbPHcN6Voxh

Comment: lol, this is awesome. What happens when you take out the lazy loader?

Comment: how? commenting all resolve blocks of code? I have like 100! :(

Comment: For debugging purposes, I would suggest just maybe taking out a state one by one to start to isolate the problem. If you try the problem with only one state, and it is the same as when you were using all of the states, then you can begin to work on the problem isolated in just one state, and hopefully it fixes it for all of them.

Comment: as I didnt have more questions I had to re-edit this one for my new question, I solved the last problem, please check my new update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=inspinia&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.1%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Doc.lazyLoad`

It says it fails to instantiate module inspinia. So make sure to inject the module. or check that something else isn't interfering with your code.

Visit the link
[The Angular Module error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=inspinia&p1=%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.1%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Doc.lazyLoad)

Comment: as I didnt have more questions I had to re-edit this one for my new question, I solved the last problem, please check my new update

Comment: According to the documentation, this is what they did 

```$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
  modules: [{
    name: 'TestModule',
    files: ['js/TestModule.js']
  }]
});```

And 

```$stateProvider.state('index', {
  url: "/",
  resolve: {
    loadMyService: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
             return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/ServiceTest.js');
    }]```

For their ui-router, try removing them from the array and test one by one, ofcourse i.e removing the key pairs(name, serie, files)

[Doc](https://oclazyload.readme.io/v1.0/docs/with-your-router)